# What kind of int storage is this?

Tags: encoding, integer, firebird

We have an Firebird database for a (very crappy) application, and the app's front end, but nothing in between (i.e. no source code).

There is a field in the database that is stored as `-2086008209` but in the front-end represents as `63997`.

Examples:

```
Database    Front-End
 758038959  44093
1532056691  61409
  28401112  65866
-712038758  40712
 936488434  43872
-688079579  48567
1796491935  39437
1178382500  30006
1419373703  66069
1996421588  48454
 890825339  46313
-820234748  45206
```

What kind of storage is this? The aim for us here is to access the application's back-end data and bypass the front-end GUI alltogether, so I need to know how to decode this field in order to get appropriate values from it. It is stored as a `int` in FireBird (I don't know if FireBird has signed/unsigned ints, but this is showing as signed when we select it).

---

This is the definition of the field:

[image]

It is not, as far as I can tell, de-normalised. The generator `GEN_CONTACTS_ID` has `66241` against it, which at a glance looks accurate.

Comment: Do you have more examples? Do any value occur several times in the table? Can you verify that those database fields appear identical in the application?

Comment: @AndersLindahl - Updated. Each value only occurs once.

Comment: @MarkHenderson  Are you sure the number in the DB is computed only from a single "Front-End" value and not 2?  Otherwise, it looks like a deliberate attempt to make the numbers difficult to encode/decode.

Comment: @MarioRossi - no, I'm not 100% sure of this. [This is not the strangest thing I've seen in this application](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18208/1193) so if nobody here can figure it out, I'm going to assume that there's more than one piece of data stored in the field

Comment: What do the numbers in the Front-End represent?

Comment: @GuillemVicens - record identifier

Comment: My bet then would be that it is a denormalized table, and that the value stored in the Database side is actually a combination of the Front-end value and some other Ids/fields. Maybe detail records?

Comment: If you say record identifier, do you mean `RDB$DB_KEY` or simply a column in the table itself?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - question is updated with the details, but at a glance it's a normal column table. I'm not particularly proficient with Firebird so I'm digging in the dark mostly.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yes it looks like a normal column (and contrary to your note: it doesn't seem to be backed by a generator), so it looks like you really need to know what transformations the application applies. You really can't get access to the source (or reverse-engineer or decompile the program)? You might also want to try to use the Firebird 2.5 trace facility to look what queries the applications uses. Maybe the transformation is done in the query itself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - yes, you're right; the generator is not linked to the field. That's odd, because there is a generator with the correct name and number in it. I have no idea what this app is doing! I don't even know what language it's been written in to try and decompile it. It's quite old. I will try a trace program and see what that turns up, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @Mark Maybe you can upload the exe somewhere for others to peek at. Long shot, but who knows.

Comment: Are you in any way able to input 'sequential' data into your front-end (e.g. creating new customer contacts when you are the only one working in the app), then look at the backend values, and add this test data to your question?

Comment: And in addition to sequential data, try special values like 0, 1111111, 'AAAAAAA'. Note the time of your attempts in case the DB field values  are time-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on with an application that stores bitmaps in integers (just don't ask), if you express them in that form do you something useful or consistant

Comment: We canned this project months ago; but I decided to check this out. You were on the right path; the numbers did indeed seem to be bitmaps. Not entirely sure how they related to the resulting numbers, but don't really care any more. Blah.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that the problem is in the front end.  If what is stored in the DB is `-2086008209`, then what is stored in the DB is `-2086008209`.  To understand better how the application is manipulating the data, try storing other numbers in the DB and see how they are displayed.

Comment: Sure, but I need to figure out the process of getting it from whatever's in the DB to whatever's in the front end. Unfortunately I can't enter arbitrary data into the field (don't even ask why). There are tens of thousands of records - I just chose this random one in the hope that someone recognises what on earth this dickhead has done.

Comment: @MarkHenderson  I made some quick tests, and didn't find any relationship.  More cases would definitely help, though.  Whatever values are already present it the DB if you can't enter new ones.  Say 10?

Comment: I've updated with a bunch more examples. I've tried everything I can think of - converting to binary and then from binary to a ascii/ansi/unicode representation (not even close), amongst other things.

Comment: So that others don't try again: I've played with MOD and DIV, and 2-degree polynomials. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you come to this realization through logging SQL? If you havent, you may serve yourself well by using the Firebird Trace API to get that SQL: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq95/.  An easier tool to parse the Trace API is this commercial product: http://www.upscene.com/products.fbtm.index.php.

I've used these tools and other techniques (triggers etc,.) to find what an application is using/changing in the Database.

Of course, if the SQL statement is select * from table, then these tools would not help much.